# After dismissModalViewController, view is in portrait mode

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, rotation, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I have a *detail view* where i load a *help view* with a button. I am using `[UIViewController presentModalViewController:animated:]`.
In *help view* I am dismissing the view with a button. I am using `[UIViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:]`.

The problem is, after dismissing the *help view*, the *detail view* is in portrait mode, regardless of which orientation the device is in.

In all the view controllers, I have implemented `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and returned YES.

Comment: do you want to support all orientations? Or landscape only?

Comment: sorry for late answer. i want to support all orientations

Comment: I've already write the answer. If this answer help you, I'm glad to hear you accept it.

Comment: i have tested it but doesnt worked for me. next time i will try that again and if i solve it or not, i will tell you. actually i have other important things to solve first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two selective solution

**1.Officially available in iOS 5.0 and later**, you can implement

```
/* call this method when your return value from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: changes
 if the current interface orientation does not match the current device orientation, a rotation may occur provided all relevant view controllers now return YES from shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: */

+ (void)attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation
```

See also : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**2.Use the trick from [Canopus's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827763/696088)**. It's pretty fine with iOS 4.3 and earlier **BUT** It's not guarantee solution that owner answer has warned you.

Hope it helps you!