# Code to turn orientation to landscape programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, api, uiinterfaceorientation

In FirstViewController there is a button. After it is pressed, there is a modal segue that goes to SecondViewController. FirstViewController is Portrait, and SecondViewController is Landscape. In the storyboard file, I set SecondVC to Landscape but the iOS Simulator won't automatically change it's orientation.
Can someone help me find code that automatically turns SecondViewController from Portait to Landscape?

`viewDidLoad` statement in SecondVC:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated  {
    UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(YES);
    sleep(2);
    santaImageTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(santaChangeImage)
                                                     userInfo:NULL
                                                      repeats:YES];
    [santaImageTimer fire];
    image1 = YES;
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, while your attempt to call `UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(YES);` was a valiant attempt, that doesn't actually change orientation. That method is used to confirm whether a variable holding a orientation is landscape or not.

For example, `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)` will return TRUE if the `toInterfaceOrientation` holds a landscape orientation, and FALSE if not.

The correct technique for changing orientation is outlined in [Handling View Rotations](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW57) in the *UIViewController Class Reference.* Specifically, in iOS 6, you should:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

In iOS 5, the necessary method is:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Comment: By the way, pre iOS6, sometimes forcing orientation change is problematic. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366929/force-rotate-view-controller/11368949#11368949 for a workaround.

Comment: Thanks! The iOS 6 one worked. Will try iOS 5. Do you know how to detect if the user's device is running iOS 6?