# How to make application launch in specific orientation?

Tags: iphone, device-orientation

My application is running in landscape mode. I want it to launch always in this orientation:[image]

If you are holding it the other way when it launches it should flip, but without the rotation animation. How do i achieve that?

Comment: Out of interest, what purpose do you serve by always launching in Landscape Right, yet allowing Landscape Left if someone rotates their iPad back again?

Comment: this is the desire of my customer

Answer (score 1):

When launching application, You can check current orientation with:

```
UIDevice myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice]; 

[myDevice beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; 

UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [myDevice orientation];
```

Device orientation can be:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
   UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
   UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,
   UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
} UIDeviceOrientation;
```

Once You know it should be rotated,

You can - use this answer: [UINavigationController Force Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826920/uinavigationcontroller-force-rotate/10146334#10146334)

Or - if only iOS 5 and up is supported: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827763/894671

Or - if iOS 6 only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12691744/894671

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to use Landscape Right, you should simply unselect Landscape Left.

However, note that Apple may knock your submission back, as they tend to like orientations being supported where possible.

Comment: i wanna use both, i wanna LAUNCH in just one

Comment: -1 He clearly states he wants to prevent the rotation on launch. Not caring about whether its left or right.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to account for insanity.