# How do I have only one view in landscape and the rest is portrait?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, screen-orientation

I have an app where the user uses in portrait mode.

I have a gallery feature which I want to only work in landscape mode.

However my problem is that I have my orientations set as such so that all my views are in portrait.

[image]

How do I force one view to load in landscape?

And how would I do that view on my storyboard in landscape mode?

Comment: You can allow both "Portrait" and "Upside Down" device Orientation and then force the orientation in a programmatically way. But I am not sure it is a good practice  in term of `User eXperience` aspect: you shouldn't force your user to rotate its device, especially if you don't allow him to do it in the rest of your application.

Comment: How do I force it programmatically?

Comment: First of all by searching on SO ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826920/uinavigationcontroller-force-rotate

Comment: Doesn't work, deprecated methods! :(

Answer (score 0):

In my case I override the NavigationController and override the following methods:

```
public myNavController : NavigationController
{
    public override bool ShouldAutorotate ()
    {
        return ShouldAllowLandscape(); // implemet this method to return true only when u want it to
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations ()
    {
        var shouldAllowOtherOrientation = ShouldAllowLandscape (); // same here
        if (shouldAllowOtherOrientation) 
        {
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
        } 

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
    }

    bool ShouldAllowLandscape ()
    {
        return TopViewController is xController; // implement this to return true when u want it
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind this code is in Xamarin.iOS but you could do exactly the same in Obj-C
Then u could override the individual methods in ur `UIViewController`s to return true or false as you want