# Rotate to Landscape for a view - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have used the below code to force the view to landscape.

```
objc_msgSend([UIDevice currentDevice], @selector(setOrientation:), UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
```

Is apple approve this for orientation or have any chance to reject my app.Please provide your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think so. [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/orientation) state that orientation is read-only property.

To force landscape into ViewController, you can do:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

To present the ViewController in a specified orientation mode:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation;
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
}
```

For all these to happen, the plist of the project must support the orientation and:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate;
{
    return YES;
}
```

All these is assuming the view controller is not presented under same UINavigationController. For such case, you should refer to this discussion on work around of forcing rotation on UINavigationController: [UINavigationController Force Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826920/uinavigationcontroller-force-rotate)

For views that you want to force into landscape, you can always use transform:

```
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2.0);
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.Anyway apple had approved my app with objc_msgSend.